# My Ethernet connection isn't working in Loki

Tags: ethernet

A while ago, for some reason my ethernet stopped working.
Wifi does work.
Can anyobody please help?
.

> lshw -c NET
>   WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
>     *-network
>          description: Wireless interface
>          product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
>          vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
>          physical id: 0
>          bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
>          logical name: wlp3s0
>          version: 01
>          serial: 88:9f:fa:16:ac:50
>          width: 64 bits
>          clock: 33MHz
>          capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
>          configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.15.0-43-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.110 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
>          resources: irq:16 memory:fc700000-fc70ffff
>     *-network
>          description: Ethernet interface
>          product: Yukon Optima 88E8059 [PCIe Gigabit Ethernet Controller with AVB]
>          vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
>          physical id: 0
>          bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
>          logical name: enp7s0
>          version: 11
>          serial: e8:11:32:07:89:21
>          capacity: 1Gbit/s
>          width: 64 bits
>          clock: 33MHz
>          capabilities: bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
>          configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sky2 driverversion=1.30 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
>          resources: irq:24 memory:fc800000-fc803fff ioport:5000(size=256) memory:fc820000-fc83ffff
>   WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.